# is Application_Error declaration in global.asax file common for all logged in user?

Tags: asp.net, .net, web-applications

in my application i am using `Application_Error` to logged the application user.

but in my code on error i am registering error in error log system and redirecting user on error page.

now if there are multiple users then will it affect to all logged in user ?

also i am saving values in   `Application["ErrorDetails"]`

will this cause problem to all users ?
below is code

```
  protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Exception objErr = Server.GetLastError().GetBaseException();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("Error Caught in Application_Error event" + Environment.NewLine);

        sb.Append("Error Message:" + objErr.Message.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
        sb.Append("Stack Trace:" + objErr.StackTrace.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
        sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);

        log4net.ILog logger = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Global));
        logger.Error(sb.ToString());
        Exception ex = Server.GetLastError();
        if (ex is ThreadAbortException)
        {
            Server.ClearError();
            return;
        }

        Server.ClearError();
        Application["ErrorDetails"] = sb.ToString();
        // redirect to the error page
        HttpCookie SMTPCookies = new HttpCookie("ErrorDetails");
        Response.Cookies["ErrorDetails"]["ErrorUrl"] = Request.Url.ToString();
        Response.Cookies["ErrorDetails"]["Message"] = objErr.Message.ToString();
        Response.Cookies["ErrorDetails"]["StackTrace"] = objErr.StackTrace.ToString();
        Response.Cookies["ErrorDetails"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(60);

        Response.Redirect("~/pages/ErrorPage.aspx");


    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct, storing a variable in the `Application` object is not thread safe.  If 2 users quickly have an error, the `Application["ErrorDetails"]` variable may have changed by the time the 1st user loads your "ErrorPage.aspx".

Comment: but what if one user have erorr and other user dont have any error message then what ? will other user redirect on error page ?

Comment: No, the `Response.Redirect` will only be sent to the user who receives an error.